# Cannot get all websites in magento setup script

Tags: magento

I need to get all websites in my module setup script, by I always get empty array. I even tried to reduce my setup script to

```
<?php
var_dump(Mage::app()->getWebsites()); die;
```

and a result is empty array again. Magento 1.7.0.2
If I call Mage::app()->getWebsites() outside of setup scrpt all works fine. What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this in a data setup script.

"Normal" setup scripts - the ones under your module's *`sql`* folder - are evaluated/executed  as a result of the call to `Mage_Core_Model_App::_initModules()` in `::run()`:

```
public function run($params)
{
    $options = isset($params['options']) ? $params['options'] : array();
    $this->baseInit($options);
    Mage::register('application_params', $params);

    if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
        $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    } else {
        $this->_initModules();
        $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

        if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
            $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
            $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
            $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
            $this->_initRequest();
            Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
        }

        $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Notice after `::_initModules()` is called, `::_initCurrentStore()` is called - this in turn calls `_initStores()`, which populates the data that your module needs. Immediately after this, the call to `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()` will process the "data" setup scripts from under your module's *`data`* folder.

Comment: The only problem is that my module should be compatible with Magento 1.4.2.0 and 1.5.0.1. As I know, data scripts can be used only from 1.6.

Comment: Correct. You will want to load the website collection yourself with `Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_collection')`.

Comment: The problem is a little bit compplicated. I also need to create several products in my setup script and when I run this in SQL setup, I got fatal error, because Mage::app()->getStore() is called during product save. I can ask another question but the problem is the same.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from calling a separate script which runs `applyAllUpdates()` after initializing stores.